# cellinp and cellout in v.vol.rst

Tags: grass-gis, error, interpolation

I am trying to use v.vol.rst in Grass 7.0.4 to interpolate temperature values considering elevation.
The answer of Grass to my attempts is: *WARNING: Unable to create cellout raster map without cellinp*
It is first time with Grass, so I have no idea what might be wrong.

Here is the code from the command.

```
(Mon Jun 06 21:06:18 2016)                                                      
v.vol.rst --overwrite --verbose input=weceeurope_current_gsc@wce wcolumn=temperatur maskmap=wecereurope@wce elevation=wece_europe_current_3D
WARNING: Vector is not 3D
16 records selected from table
WARNING: Strip exists with insufficient data
Processing all selected output files will require 10500 bytes of disk space for temp files
WARNING: Points are more dense than specified 'DMIN'--ignored 1 points (remain 15)
WARNING: 15 points given for interpolation (after thinning) is less than given NPMIN=200
WARNING: There is less than 700 points for interpolation, no segmentation is necessary, to run the program faster, set segmax=700 (see manual)
Bitmap mask created
WARNING: Unable to create cellout raster map without cellinp
Finished interpolating
3D raster map <wece_europe_current_3D> created
The number of points in vector map is 16
The number of points outside of 2D/3D region 0
The number of points used (after reduction) is 15
(Mon Jun 06 21:06:18 2016) Command finished (0 sec)
```

I tried to use all output options, but result was the same or I got warning about more setting for cross-validation

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].